# Get selected feature attributes in GeckoFx

Tags: c#, geckofx

I am using GeckoFx in my windows form app. When I select a feature in Gecko it should fill the attributes attr1 and attr2 of 'selectedfeature' class based on geojson file that loaded to html file. I test that html file and when clicking a feature this attributes will be filled (with javascript code).

```
<div class="selectedfeature" attr1="attr1" attr2="attr2"></div>
```

and when I want to retrieve these attributes from Gecko in 'geckoWebBrowser_DomClick' event, this event is raised first and so attributes attr1 and attr2 will be empty.

I used another events but nothing happened.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the contents of 'geckoWebBrowser_DomClick' to another method 'DomClicked()' and this method called again when I get a property (SelectedFeature) that its value should be filled with attr1 or attr2.

```
private void geckoWebBrowser_DomClick(object sender, Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DomClicked();
}

private string _selectedFeature;
public string SelectedFeature
{ 
    get 
    {
        GBDomClick();
        return _selectedFeature;
    }
    private set { _selectedFeature= value; }
}
```

By this (second called of DomClicked()),

```
<div class="selectedfeature" attr1="attr1" attr2="attr2"></div>
```

are filled with click event of javascript code. But in the first call:

```
<div class="selectedfeature" attr1="" attr2=""></div>
```

click event of javascript code does not execute.